# narrowing conversion from unsigned to double

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, double, type-conversion

```
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4, ":(");
static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8 ,":(");
unsigned u{42};
double x{u};
```

g++ 4.7.1 complains about this code:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of 'u' from 'unsigned int' to 'double' inside { }
```

Why is this a narrowing conversion? Isn't every `unsigned` perfectly representable as a `double`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s086ab1z(v=vs.71).aspx

The maximum value for type double is:  1.79769e+308, unsigned int is 0xFFFFFFFF.. so no it isn't perfectly representable as a double.

Comment: This looks like it might be related: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49793.

Comment: @paulm: Huh? A `double` has a 53-bit mantissa, so can definitely represent all 32-bit unsigned ints.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: An IEEE binary64 `double` might do, but C++ doesn't require IEEE arithmetic, or 64-bit `double`, or 32-bit `unsigned`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Sure.  But is the compiler required to warn about the general case?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It's not required to warn about anything; but a warning about narrowing conversions probably should warn about all narrowing conversions, including this one.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Why is this a narrowing conversion?

Because the definition includes (with my emphasis):

> **C++11 8.5.4/7** A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>   [...] from an integer type [...] to a floating-point type, **except where the source is a constant expression** and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type.

`u` is not a constant expression, so it's a narrowing conversion whether or not all possible values of the source type might be representable in the target type.

> Isn't every `unsigned` perfectly representable as a `double`?

That's implementation defined. In the common case of 32-bit `unsigned` and `double` with a 52-bit mantissa, that is the case; but some implementations have larger `unsigned` and/or smaller `double` representations, so code that depends on that assumption is not portable.

Comment: `s/52/53/`: IEEE 754 binary64 has 53-bit significand, with 52 bits stored and 1 implicit.

Comment: The most ridiculous is that even `char x='3'; double y{x};` is also a narrowing conversion error. Conversion from `char` to `double` is a narrowing conversion!

Answer (score 4):

The warning you have because you initialize x with non-constant expression

```
Ilyas-iMac:TestC++11 sandye51$ cat main.cpp                   
int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4, ":(");
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8 ,":(");
    constexpr unsigned u{42};
    double x{u};

    return 0;
}Ilyas-iMac:TestC++11 sandye51$ gcc -o main main.cpp -std=c++11
Ilyas-iMac:TestC++11 sandye51$
```

As you can see the code above works without any warning or errors

Answer (score 1):

(Let's try:) `double` has exactly 52 bits of significant (binary) digits (according to ieee standard), whereas `unsigned int` may have good 64 bits on some other system. So the actual `unsigned int`'s width on your system may be of no value for this check.

Comment: 53 significant digits. 52 are stored, 1 is implicit.