# narrowing conversion from 'int' to 'double' and array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, initializer-list, narrowing

The following

```
int i = 0;
double d{i};
```

gives an error (in clang) or warning (in gcc) of a `narrowing conversion from 'int' to 'double'`. I found it amazing that this is really narrowing, at least until I saw [narrowing conversion from unsigned to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521016/narrowing-conversion-from-unsigned-to-double).

My *actual problem* originates from a class that contains an array and provides a constructor for specifying the elements of the array, in the simplest way possible (forwarding):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
    T a[N];

    template<typename... E>
    A(E&&... e) : a{std::forward<E>(e)...} { }
};
```

In this case, we have the following ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f84957980473a64)):

```
int i = 0;
A<double, 2> x(i, 2);  // ERROR for both 'i' and '2'
double y[2]{i, 2};     // ERROR for 'i' only
```

where `ERROR` refers to narrowing conversion as discussed above. I suspect that all those errors boil down to the one mentioned at the beginning (`double d{i};`). Is this so? Otherwise, what is happening?

Anyhow, I would really like

```
A<double, 2> x(i, 2);
```

to work, exactly as

```
double x(i);
```

works. Unfortunately, I can only initialize the array using an initializer list, which also checks for narrowing conversions. I know one workaround is to make an explicit cast in the constructor:

```
template<typename... E>
A(E&&... e) : a{static_cast <T>(e)...} { }
```

or (thanks Marc)

```
template<typename... E>
A(E&&... e) : a{static_cast <T>(std::forward<E>(e))...} { }
```

but is this the "right" way? And is it the most efficient, when `E` is a "large" type?

Comment: Why remove `forward`? Try `static_cast<T>(forward<E>(e))` with a type that prints something on copying, and notice that your cast is free.

Comment: Yes, I was between those two options. I have my `foo` type exactly for such experiments (copying, moving, everything), and I will try now. Thanks. I'll also update it in the question.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ok, I give an rvalue reference as input to the constructor, and it appears that it is only moved to the contained array, not copied (despite `static_cast<T>`). So is this **the** right way? Nothing else needed?