# Initialize Vector of Long Doubles with Initialization List of Ints

Tags: c++, list, vector, initialization

Suppose I have a simple class:

```
class Pvector
{
  private:
  std::vector<long double> point_list;

  public:
  Pvector(std::initializer_list<long double> coords) : point_list(coords)
  {}
  Pvector(std::initializer_list<int> coords) : point_list(coords)
  {}
};
```

This will not compile because the `std::vector` templated on type `long double` cannot initialize itself from an initialization list templated on type `int`.  This is rather inconvenient, however, because with the second constructor removed, I cannot do the following in my code:

```
Pvector piece_movement({E.X - S.X, E.Y - S.Y, E.Z - S.Z});
```

This is because the resultant type from my arithmetic operations is of type `int`.  So I seem to be in a conundrum.  I'd like to be able to pass integers directly into the constructor for `Pvector`, but I still want `point_list` to be of  type `long double` and (somehow) be initialized with the integers I pass in.  How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can remove the second constructor and still be able to construct `PVector` using

```
 Pvector v2{1, 2};
```

Example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

class Pvector
{
  private:
  std::vector<long double> point_list;

  public:
  Pvector(std::initializer_list<long double> coords) : point_list(coords)
  {}
};

int main()
{
   Pvector v1{1.0, 2.0};
   Pvector v2{1, 2};
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use a template constructor in `Pvector` and the use the constructor of `std::vector` that takes two iterators to initialize `point_list`.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

class Pvector
{
  private:
  std::vector<long double> point_list;

  public:

  // This is not necessary any more.
  // Pvector(std::initializer_list<long double> coords) : point_list(coords){}

  template <typename T>
  Pvector(std::initializer_list<T> coords) : point_list(coords.begin(), coords.end()){}
};

int main()
{
   Pvector v1{1.0, 2.0};
   Pvector v2{1, 2};
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but I am still not sure what to do in the situation of passing in variables that are of integer type.  Now that I think about it, I suppose I can static cast each one of them to long double, but that's not necessarily the most ideal solution either.

Comment: @JohnTravolski, that wasn't very clear to me. I am not sure how passing in variables of integer types is a problem.

Comment: Aha, your second solution appears to have corrected the problem.  I am now able to initialize my Pvector using non-constant integer values and variables even without the second constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You probably get a `narrowing conversion warning`, right?

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521166/4711812):

> **C++11 8.5.4/7** A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>   [...] from an integer type [...] to a floating-point type, **except where the source is a constant expression** and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type.

So you will get this warning every time you convert a non constant integer expression, i.e a variable, into a floating-point type. Whether the value will fit into the mantissa of the corresponding type will depend on the type (float, double, long-double) and the implementation of the type.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the extra information.  You are correct, that is the warning I received.