# Element '2': conversion from 'int' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++

I have ran into this issue on a set of code that worked fine before.

`ImGui::SetNextWindowSize({ 140.f, screen_height - 68 });`

Comment: if `screen_height` is float, change element 2 to `screen_height - 68.f`.

Comment: It seems that `ImGUI::SetNextWindowSize()` requires a pair of `float`s. The second parameter probably results to type `int`. (Hard to say without knowing how `screen_height` is defined.) While `int` has usually 32 bit nowadays, a `float` can map only up to 2^23 without loss of precision. So, the warning is justified but probably not that critical in your case. If you want to get it away you may cast `screen_height` to `float` explicitly: `(float)screen_height - 68.f` or `(float)(screen_height - 68)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [narrowing conversion from unsigned to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521016/narrowing-conversion-from-unsigned-to-double)

Comment: @Scheff It should not be a warning. The narrowing conversion should make the program ill-formed. It is just that GCC is too lenient. If you add the `-pedantic-errors` flag, it will give a proper error. Clang and MSVC give proper errors without any flags.

Comment: @walnut I wouldn't be that stricht. 2^23 is a damn big number concerning screen height. This is something the compiler cannot know but the author is able to justice. Therefore, I find a warning appropriate. And, in case, `-pedantic-errors` is available to turn warnings into errors.

Comment: @Scheff It is at least not portable, since only GCC considers it warning-only. It can easily be made portable by making `68` a floating point number as you suggested or an explicit `static_cast`. The latter would also make it clear that you are aware of the narrowing and that it should not be a problem, while the implicit cast doesn't.

Comment: "that worked fine before" If you do not remember what you changed betwee functional and broken code, then it is time to start using a versioning system.

Comment: @walnut Compilers are not mandated to give error and stop compiling. [Does the C++ standard specify that for some cases the compiling should fail with an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40807404/3309790)

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, I didn't mean to say that GCC *has to* give an error. It is only my personal opinion that it is not helpful to give only a warning, especially if other compilers give error messages.